# Demating City Union Bank

Tags: india, shares

City Union Bank Share certificate held by my wife jointly with me was returned without demat in 2007 by M/s Integrated Enterprises due to signature mismatch etc. I happened to locate the physical certificate and the covering letter rejecting the demat request only now. When approached, by M/s Integrated Enterprises say that the same has already been demated in my demat account in force and being operated by them.

Is it possible to demat without a physical certificate in the demat account of the second joint holder (that is me) ?

Comment: Please add a country code.

Comment: I'm guessing it's India based on some words I've heard before (although I have no idea what "demat" means)

Comment: @littleadv For nonIndian readers, demat (short for dematerialization) is the name used in India for the process whereby paper share certificates are stored in a central (government-run) repository, and the equivalent electronic shares are what are held in the brokerage account of the share owner. Trading then moves electronic shares between owner and seller accounts, and no paper shares are delivered by the seller's brokerage to the buyer's brokerage (as used to happen in the good old days in much of the Western world, but no more; the shares have all been dematted in the Western world).